# Stacked bar chart fill with multiple conditions ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on a stacked bar chart. I'm trying to have a column of full length, where one part will be equal to actual value, and filled with the specific (!) color, and the second part is a "filler" (100-value) which always should be beige.
How could I fill it under the nested condition (if it is filler = gray, if value = painted depending on another column(with manual color selection))?

```
my_data <-  data.frame(group = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),
                      value = c(10, 20, 30, 10))

my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(filler = 100-value)

my_data <- my_data %>% gather(key = "obs", value = "value", -1)

my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(col = case_when(value <=10 ~ "yellow",
                                              value >10 & value <=20 ~ "pink",
                                              value >20 ~ "red") 

ggplot(my_data)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=group, y=value, fill=obs), 
           stat="identity", alpha=1, position = position_stack())+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("value", "filler"), 
                    values = c("filler" = "beige", "value" = "black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_identity` for this

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_data <-  data.frame(group = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),
                                              value = c(10, 20, 30, 10))
my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(filler = 100-value)
my_data <- my_data %>% gather(key = "obs", value = "value", -1)
                       
my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(col = case_when(value <=10 ~ "yellow",
                                                                     value >10 & value <=20 ~ "pink",
                                                                     value >20 ~ "red")) 
ggplot(my_data)+
   geom_bar(aes(x=group, y=value, fill=col), stat="identity", alpha=1, position = position_stack())+
   scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

One way you can avoid manually specifying colour for the background `beige` is by simple creating `2 layers` of `geoms` one will be in background, which doesn't require any calculation and your actual values will be front of it.

```r
my_data <-  data.frame(group = c("group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"),
                       value = c(10, 20, 30, 10))

my_data %>% 
  mutate(col = case_when(value <=10 ~ "yellow",
                         value >10 & value <=20 ~ "pink",
                         value >20 ~ "red")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y= 100), fill = "beige") + 
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = value, fill = col)) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If the answer addresses your query you can accept the answer